# php code in a HTML page

Tags: php, html

I have phpbb forum and I wanted to add a field in the registration page...the modification was to enable the user to choose their role .. for example to be a moderator .. or to be a normal member or .. I am actually making the forum a bit private and I am grouping users in groups so they have a restricted access to some forums. Anyways I have the html template file and I want to get the dropdown menu list from a php file code

here is my code of the php

```
<?php
include '/blah/config.php';
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpasswd);
if(!$con)
{
    die("Couldn't Connect: ".mysql.error());
}

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT group_name FROM phpbb_groups");
$array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $array[] = $row[0];
}

mysql_close($con); 

foreach( $array as $group_name)
{
    echo $group_name."</br>"; // I want to put this value in the dropdown list in the html file
}
?>
```

here is the part of the html code that I want to edit

```
<dt><label>GroupID:</label></dt>
  <dd><select name="group_id" id="group_id"" tabindex="7" class="autowidth">I want to get the data from php in here</select></dd>
```

PS: the template file is HTML file and can't be renamed to php

Comment: I will tell you what I have been told since joining SO. 
`Stop using mysql_` and migrate to PDO here is a good tut: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: For more clarity - the `mysql_*` functions will be deprecated in PHP 5.5. It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: ok I will use PDO but what about solving the original problem itself??

Comment: Is your php file there part of the forum or is it something you made separate?

Comment: the php file is something I made .. and I want to add its output to the dropdown menu

Answer (score 0):

Okay, sorry about the last answer, didnt read your PS there...

Here's a jQuery solution, uses JSON as an output from your PHP file then an asynchronous request to fill in the dropdown.

**PHP Code**

```
// The rest of your code, then output your $array this way
header("Content-type: application/json");
$array = array("banana", "apple", "eggroll");
echo json_encode($array);
die;
```

**Your HTML (example)**

Make sure you add jquery into your HEAD if you dont already have it.

```
<dt><label>GroupID:</label></dt>
<dd><select name="group_id" id="group_id"" tabindex="7" class="autowidth"></select></dd>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $.get('sefesf.php', {"q":"1"},  function(data) {
           if(data.length > 0)
           {
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++)
                {
                    $('select#group_id').append('<option>' + data[i] + '</option>');
                }
           }
       }); 
    });
</script>
```

Be sure to change sefesf.php to your php file with the json output and {"q":"1"} to {} if you dont need any GET parameters sent.

Comment: all is good but what do u mean by adding jquery into ur head .. I am sorry I didn't use jquery before ..